# Answering questions that might be duplicates

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicates

I'm still fairly new to the Workplace community and with the amount of questions amassed through this site's history, I have honestly no way of knowing whether a new question is a duplicate or not at first glance, and would most likely find out only after I'd already given an answer.

My question is, should I check first if a certain question I find interesting is a potential duplicate before answering? And if so, how do I go about doing it?

Comment: I'm not sure if you have to, but if you do, the "related" in the sidebar is a good start.

Comment: I'm really just wondering if answering a question that I didn't know was a duplicate is still a good thing or is directing the OP to a much earlier existing  version of their question and marking theirs as a duplicate much better?

Comment: Somewhat ironically, this is an almost exact duplicate of [Should we refrain from answering duplicates?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4740/should-we-refrain-from-answering-duplicates), though I don't think the linked question covers how to go about finding duplicates. But that's basically just "use the search function", not sure if there's more to say on that.

Comment: If you have a good answer to a question, just answer it. There are plenty of enthusiastic folks who like to close questions.

Comment: @Lilienthal I'd say there's a slight difference in the two questions. The one you link is asking whether you should answer when you know it's a duplicate. This question is asking whether you should always go looking for duplicates before you answer a question.

Comment: @DavidK Hmm, true. I'm wondering then if this shouldn't be two questions though. Q1 is a useful discussion to have on meta, Q2 is more practical and less about discussion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My opinion is that if you come across a question that you are able to answer, and you are not personally aware of any possible duplicate questions out there, then **go ahead and answer the question.**

As an answerer, you shouldn't feel obligated to search for duplicates of every question you come upon. That is something the asker should be doing, and to a certain extent you should trust that they have already done that. If there is a duplicate out there that you don't know, someone else will likely find it and mark it. You shouldn't feel bad if a question you answered ends up begin marked a duplicate, since you acted in good faith and were not aware of the other question. At that point you can even go read the answers on the other question and see how your ideas match up.

As you get more experienced here and start to read more and more questions, you will begin to see new questions that seem very familiar, or seem basic enough that you would be surprised if they hadn't been asked before. That's when I might go in search of a duplicate - only when I already suspect that one exists.

Comment: Totally agree on this one. It's better to use your time answering than searching and searching to see if there is a duplicate out there...

Comment: Also, in the 30 seconds you spend searching for duplicates, the question has probably been closed

Answer (score 1):

The easiest two ways I've seen to find duplicates are:

1. Just copy/pasting the title into a new question box
2. Googling the title and using `site:http://workplace.stackexchange.com/ whatever the title is here` as the query parameters